# Categorize each slide by topic

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was wondering if its possible to add some sort of tagging system to each slide and then create new powerpoints grouped by topic.

Example:

```
Slide 1 --> Category A 
Slide 2 --> Category B 
Slide 3 --> Category A 
Slide 4 --> Category B 
Slide 5 --> Category B 
Slide 6 --> N/A
```

Result in 2 new powerpoints(slide 6 is ignored):

```
 Category A.pptx (Contains 2 slides) 
 Category B.pptx (Contains 3 slides)
```

Any Ideas ?

I am thinking about creating my tags in the comment section, read them and create new slides according to my tags, and export that code to an addin.

Example of code logic

```
Sub ConvertComments()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSlides As Slides
Dim oCom As Comment

Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides

For Each oSl In oSlides
    For Each oCom In oSl.Comments
       //do stuff here
    Next oCom
Next oSl
Close 1
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems quite reasonable.   Are you having a specific problem with implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are the only person managing the deck content, I would recommend not using any data type that the user has access to via the UI (e.g. easy to delete all comments from a deck) and to rely on other data types that can only be accessed programmatically. You could use any of the following:

```
oSl.Name = "category1" ' only good for one 'tag'
oSl.Tags.Add "CATEGORY1", "TRUE" ' good for multiple tags
oPres.CustomDocumentProperties ' in UI but not easy to find
CustomXML
```

Comment: I'd go with Jamie's suggestion to use Tags. They'll be a little more complicated to use but are FAR more reliable and flexible.  And regardless of how you've identified the slides, I'd save a new copy of the entire presentation, then delete the un-wanted slides rather than trying to create a new presentation from just the wanted ones.  Far simpler.

Comment: thank you for your input, but I have something like 100 ppt over 3 years. I would have gone for the save as option but I need not only to categorize them by topic (save the whole pres. in a different folder) but also extract many slide in different folders. Its a lot of manual work. I wanted comments because I will not be the only one doing that.

Comment: At the root of your original request is the need to enter some kind of text-based meta data per slide. Is that correct? If so, the data entry part is a fixed work load so surely it doesn't matter if you use comments or tags or any other data mechanism, as long as you create the easiest UI in order to enter the data speedily and that could be implemented at the most basic level with a single text box control in an area of the the ribbon of your choice. Or am I missing something else here?